# Python 2.7.15 Module 'ssl' not working properl

Tags: python, ssl, module

Recently, I have been working on some python (2) programs that require me to connect to a 'https' site. To do this I have been using the ssl module to wrap sockets etc.

```
import ssl
ssl_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(...)
```

I have also been using the urllib2 module to do this automatically, which to my knowledge, requires httplib and ssl etc. However, just today, I have been using it again exactly in the same way but now a lot of the functions in the ssl module have just... well, disappeared? On my other Linux machine when I execute:

```
import ssl
dir(ssl)
```

It brings back at least 50 odd classes and sub functions for it such as "wrap_socket" and "_create_default_https_context"; functions that are required for me at the moment. Now however, since today, I have been using it in exactly the same way, which now for some reason does not have the functions "wrap_socket" or "_create_default_https_context". And also now when I execute:

```
import ssl
dir(ssl)
```

It only brings back:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__','__name__','__package__','extractor', 'httplib', 're', 'request', 'socket', 'ssl']
```

Instead of about 10X more functions than when it was working? I have tried reinstalling python, updating it, reinstalling the whole machine (Linux) and the same thing happens. I am very lost as to why this is happening and it is a pain because the urllib2 and httplib modules require the ssl module to work on "https" sites. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks :) Pete.

Comment: Maybe you called an own module `ssl`. Try `print(ssl.__file__)`.

Comment: Oh wow >.> You're right! I had a seperate file in there called "ssl.py" and it was conflicting. I feel like such an idiot. Thank you so much. I uninstalled everything for this!